# how to focusNode.hasFocus scrolling listview to scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent?

Tags: flutter

> how to focusNode.hasFocus scrolling listview to scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent?
>
> i learn it https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus

my code :

```
  class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scrollController = ScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        controller: scrollController,
        children: [
          Text('Login'),
          FormLogin(scrollController: scrollController),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormLogin({
    super.key,
    required this.scrollController,
  });

  final ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  State<FormLogin> createState() => _FormLogin();
}

class _FormLogin extends State<FormLogin> {
  late FocusNode phoneFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    phoneFocusNode = FocusNode();
    setFocusListener();
    super.initState();
  }

  setFocusListener() {
    phoneFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (phoneFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        widget.scrollController.animateTo(
          widget.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.linear,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    phoneFocusNode.addListener(() {
      super.dispose();
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        InputText(
          label: 'Phone Number',
          focusNode: phoneFocusNode,
        ),
        Button(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Verify'),
        ),
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

> i want that when the textfield is focusnode.hasFocus = true then the listview will scroll to the bottom of

> i want that when the textfield is focusnode.hasFocus = true then the listview will scroll to the bottom of

Comment: Did you add widget.scrollController to the Listview as a controller?

Comment: yes i can add controller in listview, and i send to statefulwidget input @etornam

Answer (score 0):

`[UPDATED]` Your `TextField` shouldn't be in the `ListView` because it needs to stay focused when you tap on it so it breaks the scroll. Change your `LoginPage` like below and it will work:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FormLogin(scrollController: scrollController),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              controller: scrollController,
              children: [
                // for loop to generate some scrollable items just for demo purposes
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) Text('Login'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no changes have occurred. keep in mind listview is above stateful. stateles listview has a controller and i am sending it to a stateful textformfield @ante-bule

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your comment.

Comment: not working, stateless widget -> scaffold -> listview children :[  statefull( TextFormField )  ]

Comment: It is working, you need to adjust it to your needs (situation/structure). Or paste your full code for me to have an exact view of the structure.

Comment: i just updated it. Let me see @ante-bule

Comment: I updated my answer again, it should fit your question now.

Comment: it's the same as before. take a look at my code again @ante-bule

Comment: Sorry but I will no longer respond to this question, my answer is working and you can test it and see it. Good luck